# Instagram webhook does not fire for testing

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have all the configuration to receive webhooks from IG.

The comments one and the rest work, that is, they arrive to the backend, but the "messages" one never arrives.

Does anyone know if this is working from the FB panel?

I tried running the webhook from the FB panel.